# Algorithm to compute the deep diagonals of Pascal's Triangle

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, pascals-triangle

Given the deep diagonals of Pascal's triangle:

```
          1
        1   1
      1   2   1
    1   3   3   1
  1   4   6   4    1
1   5   10  10   5   1

1st diagonal: 1 1 1 1 1 ...
2nd diagonal: 1 2 3 4 5 ...
3rd diagonal: 1 3 6 10 15 ...
4th diagonal: 1 4 10 20 35 ...
```

Is there an algorithm to compute the first k terms from any ith diagonal?

Comment: What do you mean by "deep diagonal"?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PascalsTriangle.html   The deep diagonals would be the opposite of the shallow diagonals, which you sum to get the fibonacci sequence

Comment: What do you mean by "opposite"?

Comment: Will you please look at the link I have provided to search for "shallow diagonals" and then compare that result to my example?

Comment: You can read the "shallow diagonals" by starting in any row of the triangle and reading the 1st number in that row, then reading the second number in the row up, the third number another row up so on...

The deep diagonals would be read by doing the opposite. Start in any row at the first number, then read the 2nd number one row down, then the 3rd one more row down, so on.. This is pretty simple.

My professor uses the terms "shallow" and "deep" diagonals. I don't know if it's a real term, but it shouldn't be that difficult to infer the meaning.

Comment: This is simple, but not obvious. To me, "opposite" sounds like a diagonal whose slope in the standard visual representation of Pascal's triangle is the negative of that of a shallow diagonal - and doing that just gets you another shallow diagonal. Your question reads like "given the diagonals of Pascal's triangle, how do I find the first k terms of a diagonal?", to which the obvious answer is "look them up in the diagonals you were given". It could have been made much clearer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, this is covered in Wikipedia. Here you go:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself

Comment: [Link-only answers are a poor practice.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) An answer should answer the question, not just point you to a different answer. Especially if the linked page changes or disappears, the answer should still remain valid.

Comment: This "answer" should have been a comment.

Comment: I could copy-paste it from Wikipedia, but the formulas would not come out right. This conveys the information perfectly, there's no need for me to paraphrase it and bungle up the details.

Comment: Also, the "link-only answers are poor" article assumes that you link to something which does not cover the answer precisely. In this case, my link is an exact answer.

Comment: @StilesCrisis And I quote - "I think that links are fantastic, but they should *never* be the only piece of information in your answer." ("never", there's no "except when..." there - did you read that answer?). It doesn't matter what the link says. Knowing the basics of mark-down ([so] formatting) should allow you to rewrite the equations.